# Selenium Webdriver giving Stale element Exception (sometimes it works, most of the time it doesn't) (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, ui-automation, browser-automation

i am using selenium webdriver to automate my website (v4.3) and selenium-wire(v5.1) to run my chrome(112.0.5615.49) in headless Mode.
The browser here is behaving in a very weird way. For a particular element which i am getting with id is giving stale element exception and sometimes it works. I am extracting the element by using the id.
Here is the code snippet for my driver initiation file:

```
def setup(request, cmdopt):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    service = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    service.logging_path = '/home/admin/logs/chromedriver.log'
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
                              executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', service=service)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    request.cls.wait = wait
    request.cls.environment = cmdopt
    request.cls.traceid_and_bookingid = None
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

Here is the snippet where i am trying to access the element:

```
try:
    self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='unique ID']"))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    self.wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='unique ID']"))).click()
```

what am i doing wrong? is there any way to mitigate the above problem?

i have already tried using ID, CSS, CLASS, TAG as the expected condition while testing

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) usage (as seen from your `webdriver.Chrome` call), that is slowing things down enough that between `self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='unique ID']")))` and the `.click()`, the element on the page has already reloaded somehow, and that caused your `StaleElementReferenceException`. There's a better way to handle the click, which is by using `EC.element_to_be_clickable` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located`:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='unique ID']"))
)
element.click()
```

That can help as long as selenium-wire isn't continuously reloading the page. (In which case you may want to create a method around that which loops through until it can click without the `StaleElementReferenceException`.)